# Android geofire get a list of users within certain radius

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to add all users to a List which are within a certain distance from a users location. I have successfully gotten a users current location and I store this in my database using geofire. I know I have to use geofire to query the results but I am unsure on how to add the users to my list. I believe that this is done within the onKeyEntered method but I am unsure.

```
    private void addLocationToDB()
{
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leaderboard").child(userID);

    geoFire = new GeoFire(database);

    geoFire.setLocation("Location", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error)
        {
            if(error != null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem storing users location - onComplete: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            else
            {
                getListNearbyUsers();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void getListNearbyUsers()
{
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), 1);

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location)
        {
            nearbyUsers.add(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for the answer I figured out my mistake. This method should take the userID as a argument not "Location". I can then get all "keys" as userID and filter the data. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

```
geoFire.setLocation("Location", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error)
    {
        if(error != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Problem storing users location - onComplete: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        else
        {
            getListNearbyUsers();
        }
    }
});
```